# egrep needs to match exact values, but is catching more than intended

Tags: shell, grep

Given the following code:

```
for u in `cat /tmp/expiring` ; do
  /var/tmp/pwx $u egrep [12345] >> /tmp/reallyexpiring
done
```

and the input to that for loop from /tmp/expiring looks like:

```
bjones password good 25 to expire
rsmith password good 3 to expire
```

/tmp/expiring will have several lines, all with a report about how many days till the account will expire and with one user per line.

Later in the script a mailx command is invoked to send email but just to those whose passwords are expiring in 1 to 7 days.

The problem is that the grep statement matches 25 days and other values that are above the 7 day threshhold.

Any ideas on how I can modify the script to match just the discrete values of 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 ? 25 for example matches because of the 2 in the number 25.

Comment: "+[1-7]+" should do it, where the pluses are actually spaces

Answer (score 1):

If you are sure a space (or another fix character) will be before and after your number, you can do

```
grep " [1-7] "
```

in your case,

```
/var/tmp/pwx $u grep " [1-7] " >> /tmp/reallyexpiring
```

#### Test

```
$ cat a
this is 2 and
this is 23 ho
but this is 8
and this 7 is seven

$ grep " [0-7] " a
this is 2 and
and this 7 is seven
```